# Is it possible to move an application to a new app pool with a batch file?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, iis, iis-7, application-pool

Lets say I have a website called "MyApp" that exists on the wwwroot folder in iis.
I also have an app pool called "AppPool2" that I want to move "MyApp" to this app pool.

Is it possible to my my website to AppPool2 with a bat file or a powershell command?

Comment: I don't have IIS available to me so I'm not comfortable making this an answer, but can you `appcmd set app -app.name:MyApp -applicationPool:AppPool2`?

Comment: All operations you do in IIS Manager can be done via command line (mostly via PowerShell cmdlets), so possibility is never a question. About how to, you should start from search engines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv>appcmd set app "Default Web Site/MyApp" /applicationPool:AppPool2
```